# Eclipse - Java - Can't find excat line in debugger where program terminates

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, runnable

I got a strange problem.
I wrote a program that simulates a 'Draughts' game, wrote in java, with GUI. I wrote a whole hierarchy with interfaces, calsses and so on. 
When I run My app via 'application' class, I get an Exception, which directs me to the function isEnptyLocation (As you can see, second line in Console). but When I debug my program to find what happened - it doesn't even get there, it gets stuck in the line:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
```

which is in my Main method.

So I don't even get to where the bug really occurs.
What can I do?

Thanks you

I[image]

Comment: I would add a break point at `Application window = new Application()` and wait till the debugger hits it

Comment: Or look in the debugger window so see if there is another thread that is suspended

Comment: As I can see the breakpoints are not checked. If a breakpoint can be sucsessfully installed the icon changes and you can see a check mark on it. Maybe the code you are looking at is not the code that runs. In the stacktrace I can see that the exception occurs in the constructor code of the Game class (Game.<init>). Try to set the breakpoint there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answers.

The code that runs is Application - that one that should run.
The breakpoints are checked, you can see the circles in the left...and so does the 'Application window = new Application()' breakpoint (again, easy to see)

I added breakpoint at the 'Game class (Game.<init>).' too, but the debuggers terminates at the stage I displayed here.

This is the strange part, cause I can't see the exact event. Maybe it has to do with the Runnable part? I'm not very familiar with threads.